# Как добавить native dll в проект в Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio, library

Проект, написанный на языке C#. Среда: Visual Studio 2012.
При добавлении через ссылки->добавить ссылку-> обзор выдает ошибку.

Comment: Напишите что за ошибку выдает.

Comment: Не удается добавить ссылку на "../TRANS2QUIK.dll".Убедитесь, что файл доступен, и является допустимой сборкой или компонентом COM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нельзя добавить native dll в references.

Однако, можно импортировать функции из любой native dll тем же способом, как это делается с winapi:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string className, string windowName);
```

Comment: Помогло,спасибо!

Comment: @brainbuggged, в таком случае стоит принять ответ нажатием на галочку слева от него.